# Getting a "query already running" error when using Vertx PG client

Tags: java, vert.x

I am trying out multiple insert queries into a PG table using Vertx Async PG Client

I am using the AsyncSQLClient from the package "io.vertx.reactivex.ext.asyncsql"

The main problem I am facing is

> Using the same connection, I am not able to perform multiple **insert** queries using the client. The first query gets logged but the subsequent query throws an Exception saying that a "query is already running". I have noticed this happening with multiple **select** queries as well.
>   Is there a mechanism to queue the queries using the same client?

The following is the code snippet of what I am trying to do

```java
private void testVertxPgClient(RoutingContext cx) {
        AsyncSQLClient pgClient = getPgConfig(vertx);
        pgClient.getConnection(res -> {
            if(!res.succeeded()) {
                log.error("Error connecting to PG, Cause {}", res.cause().toString());
                return;
            }
            SQLConnection connection = res.result();
            try{
                log.info("Connection Successful");
                for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
                    String fname = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5,10);
                    String lname = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5,10);
                    log.info("Fname {}", fname);
                    log.info("Lname {}", lname);
                    String email = String.format("%s.%s@xyz.com", fname, lname);
                    log.info("Email {}", email);
                    LocalDate dob = LocalDate.now().minus(Period.ofDays((new Random().nextInt(365 * 70))));
                    log.info("DOB {}", dob.toString());
                    String query = String.format("insert into test1(name, email, dob) values ('%s', '%s', %s)",
                            fname + lname, email, dob.toString());
                    connection.update(query, response -> {
                        if(!response.succeeded()) {
                            log.error("Error inserting entries into test1, Cause {}", response.cause().toString());
                            return;
                        }
                        log.info("Success inserting entry for {}", fname);
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception inserting entries into test1, Message {}", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                connection.close();
            }
        });
    }
```

The output I am getting is as follows

```
2019-08-16 22:32:01.008 UTC [vert.x-eventloop-thread-4] DEBUG  - Successfully logged in to database
2019-08-16 22:32:01.021 UTC [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO - Connection Successful
2019-08-16 22:32:01.024 UTC [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO - Fname iIWHcil
2019-08-16 22:32:01.024 UTC [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO - Lname MWfkbsQf
2019-08-16 22:32:01.024 UTC [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO - Email iIWHcil.MWfkbsQf@xyz.com
2019-08-16 22:32:01.084 UTC [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO - DOB 1991-06-19
2019-08-16 22:32:01.088 UTC [vert.x-eventloop-thread-4] DEBUG - Executing direct query (insert into test1(name, email, dob) values ('iIWHcilMWfkbsQf', 'iIWHcil.MWfkbsQf@xyz.com', 1991-06-19))
2019-08-16 22:32:01.094 UTC [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO - Fname QFFfSQh
2019-08-16 22:32:01.094 UTC [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO - Lname hVDGViA
2019-08-16 22:32:01.094 UTC [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO - Email QFFfSQh.hVDGViA@xyz.com
2019-08-16 22:32:01.095 UTC [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO - DOB 1978-11-18
2019-08-16 22:32:01.095 UTC [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] ERROR - Can't run query because there is one query pending already
2019-08-16 22:32:01.128 UTC [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] ERROR  - Exception inserting entries into test1, Message [1] - There is a query still being run here - race -> false
```

Where am I going wrong in this?

Comment: If you want to execute multiple queries, then i recommend using batch operations from vertx, check their docs https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-sql-common/java/#_batch_operations

Answer (score 0):

You use the `batch` utility rather than issuing multiple updates using the same connection (where you would need to handle multiple commits manually).

Here down a slightly modified version of your code snippet:

```
private void testVertxPgClient(RoutingContext cx) {
    AsyncSQLClient pgClient = getPgConfig(vertx);
    pgClient.getConnection(res -> {
        // ...
        SQLConnection connection = res.result();
        try {
            log.info("Connection Successful");
            List<JsonArray> parameters = new ArrayList<>(10);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                String fname = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5, 10);
                String lname = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5, 10);
                log.info("Fname {}", fname);
                log.info("Lname {}", lname);
                String email = String.format("%s.%s@xyz.com", fname, lname);
                log.info("Email {}", email);
                LocalDate dob = LocalDate.now().minus(Period.ofDays((new Random().nextInt(365 * 70))));
                log.info("DOB {}", dob.toString());
                parameters.add(new JsonArray().add(fname + lname).add(email).add(dob));
            }
            String query = "insert into test1(name, email, dob) values ($1, $2, $3)";
            connection.batch(query,
                  parameters,
                  response -> {
                      if (!response.succeeded()) {
                          log.error("Error inserting entries into test1, Cause {}", response.cause().toString());
                          return;
                      }
                      log.info("Success inserting entry for {}", fname);
                  });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception inserting entries into test1, Message {}", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }
    });
}
```